# df search for null cols based on groupby of another col?

Tags: python, dataframe, null, nan

Looking for input. trying to find cols that have one of the other cols population groups null.....like if one machine's sensors stopped working.

```
Group   col1    col2    col3
A       NaN     9.94    93.78
A       NaN     1.11    50.56
A       NaN     6.20    26.18
A       0.13    8.46    92.36
A       NaN     5.31    70.67
B       NaN     4.56    NaN
B       0.05    4.44    NaN
B       NaN     6.36    NaN
B       NaN     5.36    NaN
B       NaN     NaN     NaN


#drop cols that have>85% null
nan_cols85 = [i for i in df.columns if df[i].isnull().sum() > 0.85*len(df)]
df.drop(nan_cols85,axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I've put together this 85%test, but it simply takes all rows of that column together. How can I test if all rows of GroupA are null, even if GroubB has valid data?

for example: col1 fails the 85% test, but col3 does not.I want to identify col3 as a failure and drop that col as well

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there sample (small) data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar logic in a `groupby` aggregation to determine which columns to drop:

```py
nan_groups85 = df.groupby('Group').agg(lambda g:g.isnull().sum() > 0.85*len(g))
# 
#         col1   col2   col3
# Group
# A      False  False  False
# B      False  False   True
```

Note that for your sample data the ratio for each group in `col1` is only 80%, so it doesn't meet the test.

Now you can use `any` to logically OR the values for each column:

```py
nan_cols85 = nan_groups85.any()
#
# col1    False
# col2    False
# col3     True
# dtype: bool
```

Finally we can drop the columns whose value is `True`.

```
df = df.drop([col for col, isnan in nan_cols85.items() if isnan], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Group  col1  col2
0     A   NaN  9.94
1     A   NaN  1.11
2     A   NaN  6.20
3     A  0.13  8.46
4     A   NaN  5.31
5     B   NaN  4.56
6     B  0.05  4.44
7     B   NaN  6.36
8     B   NaN  5.36
9     B   NaN   NaN
```